# When to use explicit string or from a constant string

Tags: string, constants, configuration-files

In terms of strings I understand the need to have strings am going to reuse overname wrapped away somewhere in an XML file or configuration section for strings such as Company Name.

The problem am having with this is where to draw the line on using configuratioh or locally expressed strings?

What decides whether to have the string content wrapped away in a configuration file or to just have the string assigned there and then in a method?

Where am corporate branding a site then yes any corporate aspect strings I will put in a configuration file. Other aspects such as file locations etc will also go in a configuration file.

However, I have found myself discussing with others when I do this as oppose to having an explicit string defined within a method.

Do you have certain criteria that define when to use strings from a configuration section as opposed to being explicitly defined in a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use configuration when you need to be able to change functionality without redeploying/recompiling.

If your string is reused within your application but the functionality involved is not something you want to be configurable, use a constant.

Comment: If am required to change copyright information in the footer of an aspx page for instance. Would this not require a redeployment regardless of whether it is functionality or a text change in your organisation? Working in a larger org this would require a redeployment regardless.

Comment: @Gary Thorpe - If this was information that was only in a `.config`, there would be no need to redeploy the whole web application.